# Trying to set cookie from server side but not set on my client browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I am trying to set cookie on my client browser from server side.
Using nodejs and express.

When I try to signup the the cookie sent properly in my response object, but it is not set on my client browser. And when I try to use my protected API which requires token then its also not sent to server automatically even it is on same site.

This is  my serverside code.

```
const signup = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user_exist = await users.findOne({ username });

    if (user_exist) {
      res.status(201).json({
        code: 0,
        message: "Account already exist with this usename."
      });
      return;
    }

    const hash_password = await encrypt_password(password);

    const user = new users({
      full_name,
      username,
      password: hash_password,
      profile: gender === "Male" ? boy_profile : girl_profile,
      gender
    });

    const save = await user.save();

    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: save._id,
        username: save.username,
        profile: save.profile,
        gender: save.gender
      },
      process.env.SECRET_KEY,
      { expiresIn: "30d" }
    );

    res.cookie("token", token, {
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: "Strict"
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      code: 1,
      message: "User created successfully.",
      data: save
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      code: 0,
      message: "Internal Server Error."
    });
  }
};
```

My response object is

[image]

My cookie inside dev tool

[image]

Comment: You are checking the cookies for `http://localhost:3001` in your second screenshot there, but you have _set_ the cookie for the host `172.17.135.11`.

Comment: But when I change my IP to localhost get same issue

Comment: @AbhishekPoddar what does the HTTP response in that case (from `localhost`) look like? You only posted the 172.17.135.11 response.

Comment: can you please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

can you check for redirects :

If there are redirects happening after setting , make sure that they are not creating problem with cookie setting process

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. Can you please elaborate little more

Comment: @AbhishekPoddar this answer is not the problem; your cookie is being set. Your problem is that you're looking for the cookie in the wrong place.

Comment: Then from where I should look for

Comment: Your cookie is being set for `http://172.17.135.11` so it will not be visible as a `localhost` cookie.